# typeof code i think there is something weird

Tags: javascript, typescript

When i delete just x from typeof x and runit gives numberobject as a output with no spaces when i  just delete y from type y and run it gives nothing

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>JavaScript Strings</h2>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    // x is a string
    let x = "John";

    // y is an object
    let y = new String("John");

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      typeof x + "<br>" + typeof y;
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a variable like this; `var a = "hello world"`, you're using a string literal to create the string. But when you create a variable like this; `new String("hello world")`, you're actually instantiating the "String" object.
When replacing a string object, a new object is created each time, but with a string literal, it is only replaced.

The problem that you're mentioning is happening because you are using the `typeof()` function without any paranthesis, which means your code is trying to use `+ "<br>"` as the arguments. The type of `+ "<br>"` is a number, that's why it's telling you it's a `number` in the same line as `object` (The `<br>` isn't being rendered because you used it in the function). Instead, use 'typeof' like `typeof(VAR)` instead of `typeof VAR`.

Comment: Consider marking my answer as correct so other people know what the correct answer is. :)